# JavaScript - How This Can Be Written In Few Lines?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to learn JS. For several hours I've been struggling with connecting things to array, then adding functions, I wanted it to go with .forEach blabla.. Kinda gave up and made it the longer and not really complicated, easiest way which I really dislike. If you could give me any tips how to write this shorter I would be very grateful.

```js
function calc() {
    var hp = document.getElementById("hpMob").value;
    var hpz = "potwor posiada: " + document.getElementById("hpMob").value;
    var a = "Flame dmg: " + (hp * 0.05) * document.getElementById("resFire").value /100;
    var b = "Freeze dmg: " + (hp * 0.05) *document.getElementById("resIce").value /100;
    var c = "Divine dmg: " + (hp * 0.05) * document.getElementById("resHoly").value /100;
    var d = "Zap dmg: " + (hp * 0.05) * document.getElementById("resEnergy").value /100;
    var e = "Wound dmg: " + (hp * 0.05) * document.getElementById("resPhysic").value /100;
    var f = "Poison dmg: " + (hp * 0.05) * document.getElementById("resEarth").value /100;
    var g = "Curse dmg: " + (hp * 0.05) * document.getElementById("resDeath").value /100;
    /* var allId = 
      document.getElementById("resFire").value;
    +  document.getElementById("resIce").value;
    +  document.getElementById("resHoly").value;
    +  document.getElementById("resEnergy").value;
    +  document.getElementById("resPhysic").value;
    +  document.getElementById("resEarth").value;
    +  document.getElementById("resDeath").value;
    */

    // var lista = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g];

    var tekstPisany = hpz + "<br>" + a + "<br>" + b + "<br>" + c + "<br>" + d + "<br>" + e + "<br>"+ f + "<br>" + g + "<br>";

  
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = tekstPisany;
};
```

```html
    <form>  <center>
        HP Moba: <input type="text" class="hp" id="hpMob"><br /><br />

        Fire:   <input type="text" class="x" id="resFire"> <br />
        Ice:    <input type="text" class="x" id="resIce"> <br />
        Holy:   <input type="text" class="x" id="resHoly"> <br />
        Energy: <input type="text" class="x" id="resEnergy"> <br />
        Physic: <input type="text" class="x" id="resPhysic"> <br />
        Earth:  <input type="text" class="x" id="resEarth"> <br />
        Death:  <input type="text" class="x" id="resDeath"> <br />

        <button type="button" onclick="calc()">Oblicz</button>
    </form>

    <p id="result"></p>
</center>
```

And super extra code I really wanted to work few days ago:

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");
function click(){
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = calc();
};

const final1 = [
    "Flame",
    "Wound",
    "Poison",
    "Freeze",
    "Curse",
    "Divine",
    "Zap",
];


function calc() {
    var wynik = document.getElementById("mobHp") * 0.05 * document.getElementsByTagName("textarea").value / 100
    
        if (document.getElementsByTagName("textarea").value === 0){
            return "Potwor posiada calkowita odpornosc na ", final1;
        }
        if (document.getElementsByTagName("textarea").value === 100) {
            return "Neutralny na ", final1, ", otrzyma ", wynik, " obrazen.";
        }
        if (document.getElementsByTagName("textarea").value > 100){
            return "Wrazliwy na ", final1, ", otrzyma", wynik, " obrazen.";
        }
        if ((document.getElementsByTagName("textarea").value < 100) || (document.getElementsByTagName("textarea").value > -100)){
            return "Czesciowo odporny na ", final1, ", otrzyma", wynik, " obrazen.";
        }
        else {
            return "Nie podales normalnych wartosci.";
        }
    
    
    
};
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("textarea").value` will not work as it returns array of elements, so you must loop these elements to get values. Also you are looking for maps structure to work with.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code seems to work and is a cleaner alternative.

How it works:

1. Creates a HTMLCollection object of classes
2. Creates an array with name `props`
3. Loops through the HTMLCollection.
4. Adds the heath to the array without any multiplication (via an if statement)
5. Pushes the other elements to the array in the format specified in your post
6. Finally, adds the array to the innerHTML of `result`, joining them with a line break `<br />`

I hope this helps you! Please bear in mind, I have added no input checking and if health is not specified the code will likely not work correctly. Hopefully this should give you a good base for improvements.

```js
function calc() {
  const fields = document.getElementsByClassName("x");
  const props = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    if (fields.item(i).id === "Potwor posiada") {
      props.push(`${fields.item(i).id}: ${fields.item(i).value}`);
    } else {
      props.push(`${fields.item(i).id} dmg: ${(a[0] * fields.item(i).value) / 100}`);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = props.join("<br />");
};
```

```html
<form>  <center>
        HP Moba: <input type="text" class="x" id="Potwor posiada"/><br /><br />
        Fire:   <input type="text" class="x" id="Flame"/> <br />
        Ice:    <input type="text" class="x" id="Freeze"/> <br />
        Holy:   <input type="text" class="x" id="Divine"/> <br />
        Energy: <input type="text" class="x" id="Zap"/> <br />
        Physic: <input type="text" class="x" id="Wound"/> <br />
        Earth:  <input type="text" class="x" id="Poison"/> <br />
        Death:  <input type="text" class="x" id="Curse"/> <br />

        <button type="button" onclick="calc()">Oblicz</button>
    </form>

    <p id="result"></p>
</center>
```

Comment: Using `onclick="calc()"` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Create a list with key-value pair which contains the id of input element as key and value as the text to display and loop that list.

Below is the code:

```js
let  data = {"resFire" : "Flame dmg",
"resIce": "Freeze dmg", "resHoly": "Divine dmg", "resEnergy": "Zap dmg","resPhysic": "Wound dmg", "resEarth": "Poison dmg", "resDeath": 
"Curse dmg"}

function calc() {
    var tekstPisany = ""
    var hp = document.getElementById("hpMob").value;
    tekstPisany += "potwor posiada: " + document.getElementById("hpMob").value + "<br>";
    for (var key in data){
      tekstPisany += data[key] +": " + (hp * 0.05) * document.getElementById(key).value /100 + "<br>";
    }
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = tekstPisany;
}
```

```html
<form>  <center>
        HP Moba: <input type="text" class="hp" id="hpMob"><br /><br />

        Fire:   <input type="text" class="x" id="resFire"> <br />
        Ice:    <input type="text" class="x" id="resIce"> <br />
        Holy:   <input type="text" class="x" id="resHoly"> <br />
        Energy: <input type="text" class="x" id="resEnergy"> <br />
        Physic: <input type="text" class="x" id="resPhysic"> <br />
        Earth:  <input type="text" class="x" id="resEarth"> <br />
        Death:  <input type="text" class="x" id="resDeath"> <br />

        <button type="button" onclick="calc()">Oblicz</button>
    </form>

    <p id="result"></p>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you could do is to make arrays with all of the things you will loop through, so you could reuse the array 'lista', then create another array that is going to have all of the ids of your HTML elements and then you make another array for those text messages you add. Then you would have to make a triple-nested loop to loop through all of the arrays, but to be honest I don't think it's worth it. If I were you, I'd leave it this way, because it's way more readable than nesting loops with separate arrays.

However I can give you 2 tips with your code:

- avoid using `var` . It's depracated and can mess up with the scope for your functions and other variables.
- in this extra code you attached you're not returning strings. In the first if statement you have something like this:

  ```
   return "Potwor posiada calkowita odpornosc na ", final1;
  ```

and as I understand, final1 is an array. Point to which element of the array you want to return. Also, use `+` insead of `,` in the returned value.
So if you would want to return the monster having resistance to Flame, you should return it this way:

```
return "Potwor posiada calkowita odpornosc na " + final1[0]
```

I hope this helped. Greetings from another Polish person :) Pozdro!